# Adding favourite tag on TeX.SE

Tags: support, tagging

On the other StackExchange it's easy to add the favourite tags from the questions page. And on the TeX.SE I find no input field for this. So, how can I add tags?

Comment: On right, below the Community Bulletin?

Comment: @tohecz Oh, thanks. On the other SE's on the right there is an input field for favourite tags.

Comment: @m0nhawk Which SE sites? It may be a question of feature roll-out.

Comment: One thing I just learned: [You can use wildcards `*` for your favorite/disliked tags.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/interesting-and-ignored-tags-now-support-wildcards/). Also see [What do "favorite tags" and "ignored tags" do?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19173)  on [metase] and [Expressing Your Tag Preferences](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/expressing-your-tag-preferences/).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the default view, the "Favourite tags" is listed under the "Community Bulletin" on the right sidebar:

[image]

However, you can also edit these tags as part of your network-specific profile when following the link to [your profile preferences](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/me):

[image]